# Swift conversion: ERROR - UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafe-pointers

I am attempting to convert my Swift 2 code into the latest syntax(Swift 3). I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer!)

Swift 2 Code:

```
let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>(calloc(height * width * 4, Int(sizeof(CUnsignedChar))))
```

Can someone please help me resolve this conversion syntax issue?

Answer (score 2):

`calloc` returns a "raw pointer" (the Swift equivalent of `void *` in C).
You can convert it to a typed pointer with `assumingMemoryBound`:

```
let rawData = calloc(width * height, MemoryLayout<CUnsignedChar>.stride).assumingMemoryBound(to: CUnsignedChar.self)
```

Alternatively use the `allocate()` method of `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

```
let rawData = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
rawData.initialize(to: 0, count: width * height)
// ...

rawData.deinitialize()
rawData.deallocate(capacity: width * height)
```